# JDBC-simulator for non-DB structures

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there a framework to quickly build a JDBC-like interface for an internal data structure?

We have a complex internal data structure for which we have to generate reports. The data itself is persisted in a database but there is a large amount of Java code which manages the dependencies, access rights, data aggregation, etc. While it is theoretically possible to write all this code again in SQL, it would be much more simple if we could add a JDBC-like API to out application and point the reporting framework to that.

Especially since "JDBC" doesn't mean "SQL"; we could use something like [commons jxpath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/) to query our model or write our own simple query language.

[EDIT] What I'm looking for is a something that implements most of the necessary boiler plate code, so you can write:

```
 // Get column names and types from "Foo" by reflection
 ReflectionResultSet rs = new ReflectionResultSet( Foo.class );

 List<Foo> results = ...;
 rs.setData( results );
```

and `ReflectionResultSet` takes care of cursor management, all the getters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [JoSQL (SQL for Java Objects)](http://josql.sourceforge.net/) is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

try googling "jdbe driver framework"  The first (for me) looks like a fit for you: http://jxdbcon.sourceforge.net/

Another option that might work (also on the google results from the search above) is the Spring JDBC Templage.  Here is a writeup http://www.zabada.com/tutorials/simplifying-jdbc-with-the-spring-jdbc-abstraction-framework.php

Comment: +1 for jxdbcon, the Spring JDBC template is only a wrapper for an *existing* JDBC driver which makes your life your more simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to create a new [Driver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) implementation for your data structure. Usually, framework using JDBC have just to be provided an URL and a driver, so if you define your custom driver (and all the things that go with it, for example [Connection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)), you'll be able to add the JDBC-API you want.

Comment: My question is: Is there a framework that helps writing JDBC drivers?

Comment: I don't really think so, a quick search on Google doesn't reveal anything like this.